# How to Change body background for different pages in ember

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, background

I am developing ember app and I would like to have white background for signup page and login page and the rest of the pages should have grey background.

At the moment I am changing colours of body tag in controller (application.js file)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isVerified:false,
  bgColour: function(){
    if(['users.login','users.signup'].indexOf(this.get('currentPath')) != -1){
      return 'white';
    }
    else{
      return 'bg-grey';
    }
  }.property('currentPath'),
});
```

Any advices how to make this better/cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to deal with a lot of arbitrary requests from our clients where the easiest way is simply to target a specific page, so we add the route name to the `body`.

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  activate: function() {
    var cssClass = this.toCssClass();
    // you probably don't need the application class
    // to be added to the body
    if (cssClass != 'application') {
      Ember.$('body').addClass(cssClass);
    }
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    Ember.$('body').removeClass(this.toCssClass());
  },
  toCssClass: function() {
    return this.routeName.replace(/\./g, '-').dasherize();
  }
});
```

That said it's a big dirty, you could create a `ThemeMixin` and set it on the routes. It's a simpler version of this: https://github.com/ronco/ember-cli-meta-tags

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Kit is pretty common, we do the same for our app. But you can simplify it a lot by avoiding generating the classname if you really only need it for a background change:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  activate () {
    Ember.$('body').addClass('bg-white');
  },

  deactivate () {
    Ember.$('body').removeClass('bg-white');
  }
});
```